# iOS Today Extension: can this be dynamically enabled and disabled from within my app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, today-extension

By default, a today extension appears in the extension list for my app as soon as the app is installed.

What I'd like to know is - is there a way, documented or undocumented, that this can extension be enabled or disabled dynamically? By disabled, I mean that it won't even appear in the list of extensions if the user tries to add it.

Hacky answers are OK if necessary, I'd really like to be able to do this.

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for this, so I won't put it in an answer, but since that would mean taking control away from the user, I highly doubt there's a way, maybe on jailbroken devices though.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez maybe I didn't make it clear - I don't mean enable or disable like the user does, I mean take the app out of the extension list completely.

Comment: I'd also be interested if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it. The exact mechanism for populating that list is not documented, but it appears that if an app bundle contains a valid, properly signed today extension, that extension appears in the user's list.

To make it disappear then, you'd have to somehow rename or move the extension bundle, or break its code signature. That might be possible with a jailbroken device, but otherwise you can't modify the contents of your app bundle at run time.